# Tiny electrical generator?

Tags: technology, electricity

#### Background

My world has a form of magic that is similar to telekinesis; that is, it makes things move. I also have technology that is essentially the same as today's real world.

Thinking about it, this seems like it could be really useful for powering certain sorts of devices. There is, in fact, a certain type of electrical generator that is powered by magic. It consists of a fixed-magnet rotor surrounded by one or more pairs of coils. The rotor has no axle or bearings; it is spun and held in place solely by magic. As a result, the generator can be fully enclosed with no exposed moving parts; is is very nearly "solid state". Of course, this means it necessarily produces alternating current (DC would require brushes), possibly in several phases, but solid state circuitry can easily rectify this into fairly constant DC.

(Alternatively, the generator has a mobile ring of permanent magnets which spins around a set of fixed coil-wrapped arms. I suspect this might actually work better, especially since the moving portion doesn't need an axle or bearings. The objective is to avoid brushes so as to minimize wear.)

#### Question

How *small* can I make such a generator? Can I make it, say, the size of a 2032 watch battery? (At least, small enough to fit in a Smart Watch?) It should be able to generate at least 2 watts. Do any such devices (obviously, unlike my magic-powered generators, they would need an axle that can be externally driven) exist in real life?

Alternatively, is there some other way I can generate the required energy in the available size, using only the ability to make things move?

#### Extensive Details

This isn't necessarily relevant, but... I've previously asked about this magic system [here](/questions/160428) and [here](/questions/160846); those might provide some interesting details. In particular, magic is powered by the metabolism of living beings. For our purposes, what this means is that the generator has a constant supply of magic-energy *as long as it is on or near a person* (or, in some cases, an animal or other living source of magic). The generator isn't a "spin up once and coast" system; it is constantly being supplied with "fresh" kinetic energy via magic (when active; they can be made to have an "off" switch, and for safety and durability reasons, will halt themselves if separated from the person "feeding" the magic or if something happens that the rotor becomes stuck).

Also, and this happens to be extremely convenient, by nature of how generators work (and by how I imagine my magic working), a magneto-type generator will always provide exactly the electricity needed with fairly low waste. Specifically, magic causes the rotor to turn at a fixed speed, which translates into the amount of magic energy used to keep the generator spinning being directly correlated to the amount of electricity being consumed by whatever is connected to it. I can just spend the (very small) amount of extra magic to keep it spinning *even if the connected device is off* with minimal to negligible consequences. (Conceivably, there would be a delay as the flow of magic adjusts to changing power requirements, but this is what power regulation circuitry is for, and I need that anyway, at least in the form of an AC/DC rectifier.)

Comment: Generators generate exactly as much power as it is consumed. A 2 W generator does not have to generate exactly 2 W: what we mean is that is can generate *at most* 2 W. An AC generator using permanent magnets is called a [magneto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magneto). A watch battery is *huge* -- such a large magneto could have been made in 1900. Today we have very very much smaller electrical generators and electrical motors. See [micropower](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Micropower) and [microelectromechanical systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microelectromechanical_systems).

Comment: "Researchers [...] have built a micro generator 10 mm wide, which [...] produces 1.1 watts." (How *tall* is it?) Okay, that sounds like 2W in 15-20mm is plausible. I'm vaguely familiar with MEMS, but a) it's less clear what their power generating abilities are (if any?), and b) one of the properties of my magic is that it's actually much harder to make it work on stuff at that scale. The parts that magic acts on will not be microscopic.

Comment: @Alexander, it doesn't work that way; see edits. I don't really care about the total *energy* of the system because it isn't meant to work that way; it's meant to provide continuous *power* given an ongoing input of magic. In fact, *because* it has no bearings, *quickly* spinning down while it still can when about to lose its magic input will be an important *feature*. (That said, I can be flexible on the "no bearings"; the desire to avoid them is a) cost and b) less friction under "normal" operation.)

Comment: So, a generator like this would leech energy from nearby humans?

Comment: @Alexander, exactly. There's a reason I gave "smart watches" as an example ; they'd be powered by the wearer, and would shut down or require some other power source when taken off.

Comment: The Pi 3 SoC and RAM, counting conversion losses, draws 3500 mW. With just the CPU stressed it sits comfortably at 80 degrees Celsius in open air. I suppose it was more than 2W of heat. My friend put his finger to it while I was monitoring the temperature - he held it for maybe 20 seconds before it hurt and the temperature didn't go down at all. Constant 2W would probably cause your smartwatch to overheat and might cause mild burns. Momentary 2W is nothing.

Comment: @JanDorniak, I don't expect it to draw 2W *all the time*; certainly when "idle", it shouldn't. I do expect it to draw a *maximum* of 2W. The goal is to not need a secondary battery to ensure a continuous power supply. That said, I'm going to remove the bonus question; per AlexP's comment, it will inherently generate exactly the power needed.

Comment: @Matthew you asked how dangerous 2W is so I tried to provide some anecdotal info.

Comment: @JanDorniak, apologies if it sounded like I was dismissing your comment. Indeed, you have a valid point, which *very fortunately* it turns out isn't actually a concern for my use case. That said, area of dissipation also matters; smart phones get *warm*, but generally don't burn you, but they also have a much larger contact area. Read my previous comment as "Erk, in that case, I'm just as happy it turns out that I'm *not* actually dumping 2W of heat *constantly*" ☺.

Comment: @Matthew :) actually, the contact area is surprisingly similar I believe for my anecdote and your smartwatch ;) although with advanced tech and that much power I'd rather go for a brace. Flexible PCBs are a thing, you know ;)

Answer (score 3):

One easy generator to make is a faraday disk or homopolar generator. And it should easily fit in your specified 2032 battery dimensions.

[image]

In the image the power is developed between the center axis of rotation and the outer edge, as the disk spins.  These power sources generate a great deal of current at a low voltage and have been used to power welding machines.  The drawback of this design is the rotating contacts.

For your application, since you have **magic**, you can fix the conductive disk, and rotate the magnets generating the field B shown in the image.  Any permanent magnets will work for your application.  To generate more power, spin the magnets disk faster.  The faster you go, the more power you get.  To get 2W out of the generate, you'll need to put in at least 2W of kinetic energy spinning the magnets plus any losses resistive losses in the disk.

The thickness of the disk is determined by airflow for cooling and the current flow delivered to the load. 1 mm of gold can carry over 40 Amperes of current safely, which is much higher than you are going to need.

Your buck-boost or resonant power converters can convert the output voltage to whatever value and waveform you need.

Comment: "you can fix the conductive disk, and rotate the magnets"... I'm not actually sure this is correct? [One source](https://overunity.com/16077/homopolar-generator-revisit/) appears to state otherwise.

Comment: @Matthew, It doesn't matter whether a conductor moves threw a magnetic flux or if the flux moves through the conductor, as long as the geometry of the disk and the magnetic flux are correct, a current will be induced in the conductor.  I read your link and it doesn't contradict my position.   The later comments by Tinman seem to be discussing a homopolar motor design where the magnets get rotated by a battery applied between the axis of rotation and edge of the disk.  And, he correctly observes that it doesn't work, and it shouldn't